# How to use (->) instances of Monad and confusion about (->)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, pointfree

At different questions I've found hints in comments concerning using the `(->)` instance of Monads e.g. for realizing point-free style.

As for me, this is a little too abstract. Ok, I've seen Arrow instances on `(->)` and it seems to me, that `(->)` can be used in instance notations but not in type declarations (that would alone be stuff for another question).

Has anyone examples using `(->)` as instance of Monad? Or a good link?

Sorry if this question may already have been discussed here, but searching for *"`(->)` Monad instance"* gives you many many hits as you can imagine ... since nearly every question about Haskell somewhere involves `(->)` or "Monad".

Comment: What do you mean "that (->) can be used in instance notations but not in type declarations"? You can do this: `type F a b = (->) a b` and this `f :: (->) a b`.

Comment: (->) is a Type-Constructor of kind * -> * -> *; Monads have to be Type-Contructors of kind * -> * (like Maybe, [], IO, ...) - so trying to instantiate Monad with (->) yields a kind-error! But you can make  (-> a) an instance of Monad! -- maybe even (a ->) could be a Monad?

Comment: Oh, thanks for this hint! So I can understand ``(->) a b`` as ``a->b``, right? So, (->) is an operator in types.

Comment: Yes: (->) is a function over types -- often called "type constructor" or just "constructor" -- expecting two types as argument and yielding a function-type as result.

Comment: @phynfo: Actually, (r ->) is a monad, and (-> r) isn't, as you run into problems implementing `return :: a -> (a -> r)`!

Comment: [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710078/in-haskell-performing-and-and-or-for-boolean-functions) has a very nicely worked example in the answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For a given type `r`, the function of type `r -> a` can be thought of as a computation delivering an `a` using an environment typed `r`. Given two functions `r -> a` and `a -> (r -> b)`, it's easy to imagine that one can compose these when given an environment (again, of type `r`).

But wait! That's exactly what monads are about!

So we can create an instance of Monad for `(->) r` that implements `f >>= g` by passing the `r` to both `f` and `g`. This is what the Monad instance for `(->) r` does.

To actually access the environment, you can use `id :: r -> r`, which you can now think of as a computation running in an environment `r` and delivering an `r`. To create local sub-environments, you can use the following:

```
inLocalEnvironment :: (r -> r) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> a)
inLocalEnvironment xform f = \env -> f (xform env)
```

This pattern of having an environment passed to computations that can then query it and modify it locally is useful for not just the `(->) r` monad, which is why it is abstracted into the `MonadReader` class, using much more sensible names than what I've used here:

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Reader-Class.html

Basically, it has two instances: `(->) r` that we've seen here, and `ReaderT r m`, which is just a `newtype` wrapper around `r -> m a`, so it's the same thing as the `(->) r` monad I've described here, except it delivers computations in some other, transformed monad.

Comment: Good answer, would like to see an example of using some monad combinators with this instance and how it unfolds.  Eg. `liftM2`.

Comment: I'd also like to add that Monad.Reader #17 contains an article on, well, the Reader Monad. Read it here: http://themonadreader.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/issue-17/

Answer (score 29):

To define a monad for `(->) r`, we need two operations, `return` and `(>>=)`, subject to three laws:

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
```

If we look at the signature of return for `(->) r`

```
    return :: a -> r -> a
```

we can see its just the constant function, which ignores its second argument.

```
    return a r = a
```

Or alternately,

```
    return = const
```

To build `(>>=)`, if we specialize its type signature with the monad `(->) r`,

```
    (>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> r -> b
```

there is really only one possible definition.

```
    (>>=) x y z = y (x z) z
```

Using this monad is like passing along an extra argument `r` to every function. You might use this for configuration, or to pass options way down deep into the bowels of your program.

We can check that it is a monad, by verifying the three monad laws:

```
1. return a >>= f = f a 

return a >>= f 
= (\b -> a) >>= f -- by definition of return
= (\x y z -> y (x z) z) (\b -> a) f -- by definition of (>>=)
= (\y z -> y ((\b -> a) z) z) f -- beta reduction
= (\z -> f ((\b -> a) z) z) -- beta reduction
= (\z -> f a z) -- beta reduction
= f a -- eta reduction

2. m >>= return = m

m >>= return
= (\x y z -> y (x z) z) m return -- definition of (>>=)
= (\y z -> y (m z) z) return -- beta reduction
= (\z -> return (m z) z) -- beta reduction
= (\z -> const (m z) z) -- definition of return
= (\z -> m z) -- definition of const
= m -- eta reduction
```

The final monad law:

```
3. (m >>= f) >>= g  ≡  m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
```

follows by similar, easy equational reasoning.

We can define a number of other classes for ((->) r) as well, such as Functor,

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
```

and if we look at the signature of

```
   -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b
```

we can see that its just composition!

```
   fmap = (.)
```

Similarly we can make an instance of `Applicative`

```
instance Applicative ((->) r) where
   -- pure :: a -> r -> a
   pure = const

   -- (<*>) :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b
   (<*>) g f r = g r (f r)
```

What is nice about having these instances is they let you employ all of the [Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad.html) and [Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html) combinators when manipulating functions.

There are plenty of instances of classes involving (->), for instance, you could hand-write the instance of [Monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html) for (b -> a), given a Monoid on `a` as:

```
enter code here
instance Monoid a => Monoid (b -> a) where
    -- mempty :: Monoid a => b -> a
    mempty _ = mempty
    -- mappend :: Monoid a => (b -> a) -> (b -> a) -> b -> a
    mappend f g b = f b `mappend` g b
```

but given the Monad/Applicative instance, you can also define this instance with

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (r -> a) where
    mempty = pure mempty
    mappend = liftA2 mappend
```

using the Applicative instance for `(->) r` or with

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (r -> a) where
    mempty = return mempty
    mappend = liftM2 mappend
```

using the Monad instance for `(->) r`.

Here the savings are minimal, but, for instance the @pl tool for generating point-free code, which is provided by lambdabot on the #haskell IRC channel abuses these instances quite a bit.

Comment: For the sake of clarity by using examples: so a simple function taking an integer and returning argument + 20 could be written like so  ``import Control.Applicative -- this has monad instance of (->) r\n add20 :: Int -> Int \n  add20= do\n p <- id \n return $ p + 20`` , thanks four your elaborated answer

Comment: Hm, the line ``(>>=) x y z = y (x r) r`` reads ``(>>=) x y r = y (x r) r``, I mean, the ``z`` should be an ``r``, or did I missed sth?

Comment: I probably screwed it up, given that I typed all of those off the cuff and I alpha renamed about half way through, to make it easier to see the rewrites.