# In Haskell performing `and` and `or` for boolean functions

Tags: haskell, combinators, pointfree

I just wrote the following two functions:

```
fand :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> a -> Bool
fand f1 f2 x = (f1 x) && (f2 x)

f_or :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> a -> Bool
f_or f1 f2 x = (f1 x) || (f2 x)
```

They might be used to combined the values of two boolean functions such as:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Data.Char

nameChar = satisfy (isLetter `f_or` isDigit)
```

After looking at these two functions, I came to the realization that they are very useful.  so much so that I now suspect that they are either included in the standard library, or more likely that there is a clean way to do this using existing functions.

What was the "right" way to do this?

Comment: Haskell, the language where everything is already in a a typeclass in the standard library somewhere. Typeclassopedia can help remedy that.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

One simplification,

```
f_and = liftM2 (&&)
f_or  = liftM2 (||)
```

or

```
      = liftA2 (&&)         
      = liftA2 (||)
```

in the `((->) r)` applicative functor.

---

**Applicative version**

Why? We have:

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
    (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)

liftA2 f a b = f <$> a <*> b

(<$>) = fmap

instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

So:

```
  \f g -> liftA2 (&&) f g
= \f g -> (&&) <$> f <*> g          -- defn of liftA2
= \f g -> ((&&) . f) <*> g          -- defn of <$>
= \f g x -> (((&&) . f) x) (g x)    -- defn of <*> - (.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
= \f g x -> ((&&) (f x)) (g x)      -- defn of (.)
= \f g x -> (f x) && (g x)          -- infix (&&)
```

---

**Monad version**

Or for `liftM2`, we have:

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    return = const
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

so:

```
  \f g -> liftM2 (&&) f g
= \f g -> do { x1 <- f; x2 <- g; return ((&&) x1 x2) }               -- defn of liftM2
= \f g -> f >>= \x1 -> g >>= \x2 -> return ((&&) x1 x2)              -- by do notation
= \f g -> (\r -> (\x1 -> g >>= \x2 -> return ((&&) x1 x2)) (f r) r)  -- defn of (>>=)
= \f g -> (\r -> (\x1 -> g >>= \x2 -> const ((&&) x1 x2)) (f r) r)   -- defn of return
= \f g -> (\r -> (\x1 ->
               (\r -> (\x2 -> const ((&&) x1 x2)) (g r) r)) (f r) r) -- defn of (>>=)
= \f g x -> (\r -> (\x2 -> const ((&&) (f x) x2)) (g r) r) x         -- beta reduce
= \f g x -> (\x2 -> const ((&&) (f x) x2)) (g x) x                   -- beta reduce
= \f g x -> const ((&&) (f x) (g x)) x                               -- beta reduce
= \f g x -> ((&&) (f x) (g x))                                       -- defn of const
= \f g x -> (f x) && (g x)                                           -- inline (&&)
```

Comment: Easier to derive if you use `liftA2` instead of `liftM2`.

Answer (score 11):

*Totally* ripping off of TomMD, I saw the `and . map` and `or . map` and couldn't help but want to tweak it:

```
fAnd fs x = all ($x) fs
fOr fs x = any ($x) fs
```

These read nicely I think. `fAnd`: are all functions in the list `True` when `x` is applied to them? `fOr`: are any functions in the list `True` when `x` is applied to them?

```
ghci> fAnd [even, odd] 3
False
ghci> fOr [even, odd] 3
True
```

fOr is an odd name choice, though. Certainly a good one to throw those imperative programmers for a *loop*. =)

Comment: Ah yes, much nicer implementations.  How could I have neglected `all` and `any`?!

Comment: fAnd = fmap and . sequence
    fOr = fmap or . sequence

Comment: I'm not sure `fAnd [even, odd] 3` is much better than `all ($3) [even, odd]` though .

Comment: And the point free version:

`filter (\`any\` [even, prime]) . flip ($)) xs`

Answer (score 7):

It's uglier if you always want two functions, but I think I'd generalize it:

```
mapAp fs x = map ($x) fs

fAnd fs = and . mapAp fs
fOr fs = or . mapAp fs

> fOr [(>2), (<0), (== 1.1)] 1.1
True
> fOr [(>2), (<0), (== 1.1)] 1.2
False
> fOr [(>2), (<0), (== 1.1)] 4
True
```

Comment: That's the first time I've seen `($x)` used in Haskell. For a second there I felt like I was back in PHP land *shudder*.

Comment: Yeah, that's always an odd one, but it is shorter than `(\f -> f x)`

Answer (score 4):

This has sortof been mentioned but in a more complex way.  You could use applicative stuff.

For functions basically what it does is pass the same argument to a number of functions that you can combine at the end.

So you could implement it like this:

```
(&&) <$> aCheckOnA <*> anotherCheckOnA $ a
```

For each `<*>` in the chain then you get another function that applies to a and then you munge all the output together using `fmap` alternately written as `<$>`.  The reason this works with `&&` is because it takes two arguments and we have 2 functions starred together.  If there was an extra star in there and another check you'd have to write something like:

```
(\a b c -> a && b && c) <$> aCheckOnA <*> anotherCheckOnA <*> ohNoNotAnotherCheckOnA $ a
```

[check this out](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors) for more examples

Comment: it not `(&&) <$> aChekOnA <*> anotherCheckOnA $ a` ?

Answer (score 3):

On top of what Don said, the `liftA2/liftM2` versions may not be lazy enough:

> `let a .&&. b = liftA2 (&&) a b in pure False .&&. undefined`

`*** Exception: Prelude.undefined`

Woops!

So instead you might want a slightly different function. Note that this new function requires a `Monad` constraint -- `Applicative` is insufficient.

> `let a *&&* b = a >>= \a' -> if a' then b else return a' in pure False *&&* undefined`

`False`

That's better.

As for the answer that suggests the `on` function, this is for when the functions are the same but the arguments are different. In your given case, the functions are different but the arguments are the same. Here is your example altered so that `on` is an appropriate answer:

`(f x) && (f y)`

which can be written:

`on (&&) f x y`

*PS: the parentheses are unnecessary.*

Comment: This works: `let a .&&. b = liftA2 (&&) a b in (pure False .&&. undefined) ()`

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher Why is it lazy for the ((->)e) or Reader Monad and not for the IO Monad?

Comment: @JohannesGerer In `f <*> a` the side-effects in `f` have to occur before the side-effects in `a`. But the reader monad has no side-effects, so it can safely ignore computations from which the results aren't needed.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using [Arrows](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html):

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&), (>>>), Arrow(..))

split_combine :: Arrow cat => cat (b, c) d -> cat a b -> cat a c -> cat a d
split_combine h f g = (f &&& g) >>> h

letter_or_digit = split_combine (uncurry (||)) isLetter isDigit
```

`&&&` (not related to `&&`) splits the input; `>>>` is arrow/category composition.

Here's an example:

```
> map letter_or_digit "aQ_%8"
[True,True,False,False,True]
```

This works because functions -- `->` -- are instances of Category and Arrow.  Comparing the type signatures to Don's `liftA2` and `liftM2` examples shows the similarities:

```
> :t split_combine 
split_combine :: Arrow cat => cat (b, c) d  -> cat a b -> cat a c -> cat a d

> :t liftA2
liftA2    :: Applicative f => (b -> c -> d) ->     f b ->     f c ->     f d
```

Besides the currying, note that you can almost convert the first type into the second by substituting `cat a ---> f` and `Arrow ---> Applicative` (the other difference is that `split_combine` isn't limited to taking pure functions in its 1st argument; probably not important though).

Answer (score -1):

If f1 and f2 are the same, then you can use 'on':

```
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
```

in base Data.Function

```
fand1 f = (&&) `on` f
for1 f = (||) `on` f
```

Typical usage:

```
Data.List.sortBy (compare `on` fst)
```

(from [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?q=on))

Comment: This does the opposite of what the question is seeking — it tests one function against multiple values (which is already handled capably by `all` and `any`), rather than multiple functions against one value.