# Make "A || B && C" point-free in Haskell

Tags: haskell, applicative, pointfree

I'm tackling a simple leap year exercise in Haskell, and I'd like to make my solution point-free. Starting from this:

```hs
isLeapYear :: Integer -> Bool
isLeapYear year = divisibleBy 400 year || divisibleBy 4 year && not (divisibleBy 100 year)
  where
    divisibleBy m y = (== 0) $ flip mod m y
```

I tried using `liftA3`, with a function doing `(x || (y && z))` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710078/in-haskell-performing-and-and-or-for-boolean-functions), but the tests do not finish and I don't know why.

So, then, I have 3 questions:

- Do you have any pointers as to how could I achieve this?
- In my first solution, what's preventing `divisibleBy` to be point-free? (Typechecker complains if I remove the arguments)
- As I mentioned before, I tried something like `liftA3 (\x y z -> x || (y && z)) (divisibleBy 400) (divisibleBy 4) (indivisibleBy 100)`, but the tests hang. Why does that happen? I'm not getting how `liftA3` works.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't always use it, but... http://pointfree.io/

Comment: So it should be: `isLeapYear = ap ((||) . divisibleBy 400) (ap ((&&) . divisibleBy 4) (not . divisibleBy 100))`. Not awfully readable, but slightly shorter.

Comment: I see, thanks! I was wondering if there was a way to make this point-free without sacrificing too much on readability, perhaps through some function that was yet unknown to me. The pointfree.io version looks a bit overdone.

Comment: `flip mod m y` seems redundant. This is better: `mod y m`

Comment: Making expressions pointfree is not an unalloyed good.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs oh I know, I was just wondering if there was a good way to make it for this situation.

Comment: @xilpex Yes, that's related to my second question, in which I was trying to make `divisibleBy` pointfree as well.

Comment: ``divisibleBy m = ((== 0) . (`mod` m))``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In my first solution, what's preventing divisibleBy to be point-free? (Typechecker complains if I remove the arguments)

You might think that these are equivalent (I am writing `flipmod` as one function for simplicity's sake):

```hs
divisibleBy  m y = (== 0) $ flipmod m y
divisibleBy'     = (== 0) . flipmod
```

But in actuality, `divisibleBy'` is now an (invalid) function that takes an argument `x` and then compares `flipmod x` to zero:

```
    ((==0) . flipmod) 5
→   (==0) (flipmod 5)
→   flipmod 5 == 0
```

Comparing a function (`flipmod 5`) and a number is certainly no good.

You'd need to write something more sophisticated, namely:

```hs
divisibleBy = ((== 0) .) . flipmod
```

So that now, properly:

```
    divisibleBy 5 6
→   (((== 0) .) (flipmod 5)) 6
→   ((== 0) . flipmod 5) 6
→   (== 0) (flipmod 5 6)
→   flipmod 5 6 == 0
```

This construction `(f.).g` can also be written as `((.).(.)) f g`, and that operator is sometimes called [`dot`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree#Dot). I don't think writing things like this is a very good idea, but it might answer your question.

---

> The tests hang. Why does that happen?

I don't know. You'll probably need to provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here, because this works fine for me as a full program:

```hs
import Control.Applicative

isLeapYear :: Integer -> Bool
isLeapYear = liftA3 (\x y z -> x || (y && z))
                    (divisibleBy 400)
                    (divisibleBy 4)
                    (not . divisibleBy 100)
  where
    divisibleBy m y = (== 0) $ flip mod m y

main = print (filter isLeapYear [1850..1950])
```

Comment: Mmm, perhaps there was a character slipping by or something, because I have checked again and it worked. Thanks @Lynn !