# What does ((->) t) mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In Haskell, what does ((->) t) mean in the type signature of instances? For example Functor, Applicative and Monad all have an instance along the lines of:

```
Functor ((->) r)
```

I can't find any explanation of what this type signature means and it's highly search engine-resistant.

Comment: `highly search engine-resistant` -- not for the SO search engine. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5310203/11683

Comment: You're right! I guess I should consider sometimes searching SO directly instead of just relying on Google.

Comment: You can also search on [SymbolHound](http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=Functor+%28%28-%3E%29+r%29).

Comment: In case anyone who happens across this question is wondering, a good search term is "reader monad".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`->` is an infix type constructor. You can compare it with `:` - an infix value constructor for list type. To use `:` alone we put parentheses around it so it becomes a prefix function application:

`(:) a b` is the same as `a : b`

Similarly, `(->) a b` is the same as `a -> b`, type of a function from `a` to `b`.

`(->) a` is a partial application of type constructor, and itself a type constructor of kind `* -> *`.

You can think of it as "a constructor of types of functions from a". E.g. `(->) Int` is a constructor of types of functions from `Int`. You can construct full function type by passing another type to it: `(->) Int String` is the type of functions from `Int` to `String`.

`instance Functor (->) a` is a functor with `fmap` operation transforming an `a -> b` function into an `a -> c` function. You can compare it with a similar `instance Functor (Either a)` which maps `Either a b` to `Either a c` by applying the `fmap` argument to `Right` values.

Comment: Thanks. This mostly makes sense to me. Still somewhat new to Haskell so it will take me some time to digest.

Comment: The `(->) r` instances are *very* difficult to understand, in my opinion. I feel relatively confident with a lot of Haskell, but I still have no intuition at all for how the `(->) r` instances work. I can *use* them, because I use them all the time, so it isn't very weird to me anymore. It's just that I wouldn't say I understand them deeply. Don't worry if you don't either. I'm sure it will come to both of us in time.

Comment: @kqr When you know what the Monad instance does, I think you can derive it in a nice way. This small note I've written starts with a very verbose (but I hope somewhat easy to understand) definition of `>>=`, and then shows how, when properly golfed, it is identical to the usual implementation you may know from LYAH for example. https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/reader_instance_derived.md#bind

Comment: @kqr Yeah, `(->) r` is really weird. Like, it allows you to re-write `diag f x = (x, x)` in point-free style as... `diag = join (,)`! When the lambdabot told me that, my reaction was "wat."

Answer (score 12):

We could use lambda functions and infix functions:

```
(->) a    =    \b ->  (->) a b  --pseudo-Haskell
(->) a    =    \b ->  a -> b    --pseudo-Haskell
```

so, read instance as:

```
class Functor f where
   fmap :: (a->b) -> f a -> f b

instance Functor ((->)r) where
   fmap :: (a->b) -> f     a  -> f     b
         = (a->b) -> (->)r a  -> (->)r b   --pseudo-Haskell
         = (a->b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)  --pseudo-Haskell
```

Comment: This was actually quite helpful for my intuition. I need to do the same thing for the applicative instance of `(->) r`!

Answer (score 4):

You could see it as the set of types `r -> a` where `r` is fixed.

A functor is a type function `m`, which means that for any type `a` you have a type `m a`. Examples are `Maybe`, `[]` and `(->) r`. The latter should perhaps better be written `(r ->)`, but I don't know if that's allowed.