# Trouble Understanding Monad (->)

Tags: haskell

In the following instance of Monad:

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    return = const
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

Is this forcing `k` to be a function of two parameters? And if so, why would you want to pass `(f r)` AND `r` to `k`?

Comment: You might like the [Monads as Containers](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monads_as_containers) section on the reader monad (search for "reader").

Comment: Yes `k` is a function `a -> r -> b`. `r` is the only instance of `r` you have and `f r` is the only way to get an `a` so you don't have much choice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use (->) instances of Monad and confusion about (->)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310203/how-to-use-instances-of-monad-and-confusion-about)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this forcing k to be a function of two parameters?

Yes.  Looking at the definition of `Monad`, we have

```
class Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Substituting `(->) r` for `m`, we have

```
return :: a -> (->) r a
(>>=) :: (->) r a -> (a -> (->) r b) -> (->) r b
```

Now, `(->) r a` is just a weird syntax for `r -> a`, and similarly for the other cases, so we get

```
return :: a -> r -> a
(>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> r -> b
```

So we can see that indeed the second argument to `>>=` must be a function of (at least) two arguments.

Why? Because a function of two arguments is just a function taking one argument and returning a function of one argument, while the second argument to `>>=` should be a function taking one argument and returning a value of the monad's type constructor; for the function monad, this value will be a function.  Hence the second argument to `>>=` will be a function of two arguments.

> [W]hy would you want to pass (f r) AND r to k?

Partly because it makes the `(->) r` type fit the uniform structure of a Monad, which is useful for lots of reasons.

Partly `k` doesn't know which function `f` you're using.  That means that, from `k`'s perspective, the two arguments `f r` and `r` really are independent --- `k` can't calculate one from the other.

Consider this function:

```
-- | 'f' takes two numbers and adds them together
f :: (->) (Int, Int) Int
f = fst >>= \ n0 -> snd >>= \ n1 -> return (n0 + n1)
```

The function `\ n0 -> snd >>= \ n1 -> return (n0 + n1)` doesn't care where its argument comes from, or in particular that its argument is the first component of the input.  So it needs both the argument `n0` and the full input.