# How to infer the type of liftM2 (==) id and (\x->x+1) id

Tags: haskell, type-inference

I am studying haskell. Could somebody explain how the two types are inferred and what does  Num (a -> a) mean?

```
liftM2 (==) id :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> Bool


(\x->x+1) id :: Num (a -> a) => a -> a
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use (->) instances of Monad and confusion about (->)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310203/how-to-use-instances-of-monad-and-confusion-about)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case we have

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

by setting `a1=a` and `a2=a` we get

```
liftM2 (==) :: (Eq a, Monad m) => m a -> m a -> m Bool
```

Now the tricky bit is that there is [a Monad instance for the function type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-621).

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    return = const
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

because of this, a function of type `r -> a` can be passed where a `Monad a => m a` is expected. Since `id :: a -> a` we get `r=a`, `m a = a -> a` and `m Bool = a -> Bool`, resulting in

```
liftM2 (==) id :: (Eq a) => (a -> a) -> (a -> Bool)
```

---

For the second type, what that type signature is saying is that there is a Num instance for the function type `(a -> a)`.

Haskell numeric literals are polymorphic and `((\x -> x + 1) id)` is actually syntactic sugar for the following:

```
((\x -> x + (fromInteger 1)) id)
```

which, by β-reduction is

```
id + (fromInteger 1)
```

This assumes that (fromInteger 1) is a function and that there is a way to add two functions together with the `+` operator. By default this is not possible but Haskell allows you to define addition for functions if you really want to.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Num (Int -> Int) where
  f + g = \x -> f x + g x
  f * g = \x -> f x * g x
  abs f = \x -> abs (f x)
  fromInteger n = \x -> fromInteger n
  signum f = error "not implemented"


f1 :: Int -> Int
f1 x = x + 1

f2 :: Int -> Int
f2 x = x + 2

f3 :: Int -> Int
f3 = f1 + f2

main = do
  print $ f3 0
```

Comment: (id + (fromInteger 1)) 0, which (+) function does compiler choose?  If it choose  f + g = \x -> f x + g x,  (fromInteger 1) 0 will get a error. By the way, you have a typo 'liftM2 (==) if'

Comment: In the example I made I only defined instances for `Int -> Int` so you need to add some type annotations to guide Haskell the correct way, like I did in my `f1+f2` example, where all the functions are annotated. If you use `((fromInteger 1) (0::Int)) :: Int` then it should work