# Combining (a -> Maybe a) and (a -> a) functions

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, dot-operator

I have two functions:

```
f :: a -> Maybe a
g :: a -> a
```

I want to create such function:

```
h :: a -> Maybe a

h x
| isJust(f x) = Just (g $ fromJust(f x))
| otherwise   = Nothing
```

How can I do it in more elegant way?

Comment: The elegant way was posted below. Still, I want to remind that using `isJust/fromJust` is arguably the least elegant way. Indeed, if one forgets the `isJust` check, `fromJust` can crash your program. A better way would be to use pattern matching instead, e.g. `case f x of Nothing -> Nothing ; Just y -> Just $ g y`. Also see [boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/) for more info.

Comment: That isn't type correct.  `g (fromJust (f x)) : a`.  I think you ment `Just (g (fromJust (f x))`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you've tagged this question with [dot-operator](/questions/tagged/dot-operator):

```
h :: a -> Maybe a
h = fmap g . f
```

For an explanation:

```
f            ::                          a -> Maybe a
g            ::        a ->       a
fmap g       ::  Maybe a -> Maybe a
(.)          :: (Maybe a -> Maybe a) -> (a -> Maybe a) -> (a -> Maybe a)
(.) (fmap g) ::                         (a -> Maybe a) -> (a -> Maybe a)
fmap g . f   ::                                           (a -> Maybe a)
h            ::                                            a -> Maybe a
```

Note that `(.)`'s and `fmap g`'s types are actually more general:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
-- b in this case is Maybe a
-- c in this case is Maybe a

fmap g :: Functor f => f a -> f a
-- f in this case is Maybe
```

However, you could also pattern match on the result of `f`:

```
h x = 
  case f x of
    Just k -> Just (g k)
    _      -> Nothing
```

Note that your original example wouldn't even compile, since `g`'s return type isn't correct.

Comment: I think this is the most idiomatic way, and expresses the idea the most clearly of all options.

Answer (score 5):

Having

```
fmap2 :: (Functor g, Functor f) => (a -> b) -> g (f a) -> g (f b)
fmap2 = fmap . fmap
```

here is a funny way:

```
h :: a -> Maybe a
h = fmap2 g f
```

`fmap2 g f ~> fmap (fmap g) f ~> fmap g . f ~> \x -> fmap g (f x)`

The [`Functor ((->) r)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5316690/3237465) instance is used here: `fmap` can be used instead of `(.)`.

Comment: Given that the user is (probably) new to Haskell, would you add some explanation? Not everyone is familiar with `Functor ((->) r)`. Using `b ~ a`, `f a ~ Maybe a` and `g c ~ a -> c` would make this a lot clearer for them.

Comment: @Zeta, I wanted to make it look like a puzzle.

Comment: so, in `fmap . fmap` the left `fmap` is in `(a ->)`, because `fmap g` is always a function, whatever the functor. the  right `fmap` here happens to be in `Maybe`. (and in owl combinator, it's in (r ->) too. nice.)

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply this:

```
h :: a -> Maybe a
h x = fmap g (f x)
```

Or the operator version:

```
h :: a -> Maybe a
h x = g <$> f x
```