# How to interpret fmap where f a = c -> d -> e

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm trying to understand some code and I'm getting myself tangled fairly well. Please help me to understand my logic, or lack thereof ...

To start:

```
*Main> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

If I just want `f a` to be a function that takes one parameter, it's okay and makes sense:

```
*Main> :t \f -> fmap f (undefined :: String -> Int)
\f -> fmap f (undefined :: String -> Int) :: (Int -> b) -> String -> b
```

I can pass in a `String` in the second param, which generates an `Int`, and then use the function in the first param to generate the `b`.

Now, I want `f a` to be a function that takes two parameters, so I substitute that in:

```
*Main> :t \f -> fmap f (undefined :: String -> Int -> Bool)
\f -> fmap f (undefined :: String -> Int -> Bool) 
    :: ((Int -> Bool) -> b) -> String -> b
```

At this point, I'm confused. I already provided the function that converts from the `String` and the `Int` into the `Bool`. How can I now provide another function that *takes* a `Int -> Bool` to convert into a `b`? Is this non-sensical or am I not reading this right?

Or maybe this is a case of a functor within a functor and more needs to be done to make this make sense? In which case, what?

Comment: does it help you if you rephrase it as `fmap f (undefined :: String -> (Int -> Bool))`? Because this is what you are saying (basically `String` stays `String` but you replace `Int` with `Int -> Bool`  to *match the needed pattern*)

Comment: @Carsten I understand that grouping, but no it doesn't help me because I'm still left with the same type signature. If my function of type `String -> Int -> Bool` is opaque to me, then there'd be no way for me to implement this `fmap`.

Comment: no there is no way to implement the `fmap` fo `f a = (String -> Int) -> Bool -> a` - at least not directly - you can always wrap this into something like `newtype MyMap a = String -> Int -> Bool -> a` and make `MyMap` an instance of `Functor` - but then you have to wrap/unwarp the constructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use (->) instances of Monad and confusion about (->)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310203/how-to-use-instances-of-monad-and-confusion-about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually no such thing as a function with two parameters in Haskell. Every function has exactly one parameter.

In particular, `String -> Int -> Bool` is a function which accepts one `String` parameter. (Of course, knowing that the result is again a function you are able to use it *as if it were* a function with two parameters.) So if you want to unify this with `f a`, you need

```
f ~ (String->)
a ~ Int->Bool
```

Indeed `Int->Bool` can itself be interpreted as a functor-application<sup>†</sup>

```
f ~ (String->)
g ~ (Int->)
b ~ Bool
```

so that `String->Int->Bool ~ f (g b)`; thus

```
\f -> fmap (fmap f) (undefined :: String -> Int -> Bool)
       :: (Bool -> b) -> String -> Int -> b
```

I don't think the function family of functors is really a good example for grasping properties of functors/applicatives/monads. List and maybes are generally much less confusing; instead of the plain function functor the equivalent [`Reader`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html) is preferred when you need that functionality (pun not intended).

Regarding your original expression, that is actually not meaningless. If we translate it to a tamer functor, we could for instance write

```
> fmap ($2) [(>1), (>2), (>3)]
            [True, False, False]
```

Much the same thing can be done with the function functor:

```
> fmap ($2) (<) 1
True
> fmap ($2) (<) 2
False
> fmap ($2) (<) 3
False
```

Of course that example is a bit too simple to be useful, but you can also implement nontrivial ones.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Note that `f` and `g` are actually *not the same functor*. We tend to call them both “*the* function functor”, but really you get a different functor for every partial application of the `(->)` constructor. That means, you can't in any way unify the two layers, even though there's a `Monad (a->)` instance.</sub>

Comment: You can unify the layers; you just can't do it with a standard `Monad`. You certainly can do something like `uncurry` generally. I would also guess that given an appropriate  relationship between the argument types, you could probably do something with indexed monads.

Comment: I think `\f -> fmap (fmap f) (undefined :: String -> Int -> Bool) :: (Bool -> b) -> String -> Int -> b` is what I was looking for. Thanks!