# How do I use my Reader: newtype R r a = R { run :: r -> a }?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm trying to wrap my head around the applicative instance for Reader by matching the type definition with some examples. One problem is I do not know how to use my Reader newtype.

My definition of Reader is

```
newtype R r a =
  R { run :: r -> a }
```

The type definition for `(<*>)` is

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Specialized for the Reader type this becomes:

```
(<*>) :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

So when I try:

```
(<*>) (+) (*2) 5 -- seems equivalent to using Reader since the types match
```

in the REPL I get `15`. I guess this is because it computes `(2*5) + 5`.

How would I do the above with my Reader newtype? And is the `a` you see in 
`(r -> a -> b)` the same `a` you get from `(r -> a)` or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: you just have to pack/unpack it from `R` when defining your `Applicative` instance: `(R f) <*> (R a) = R (\r -> (f r) (a r))`

Comment: in case you already *have* the instance you have to wrap the function/values into `R` and then you can use `run`: `run (R (+) <*> R (*2)) 5`

Comment: I guess my question was not the clearest. That is what I was wondering, will upvote if you add that as an answer. Might ask you a follow up q on the applicative instance though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use (->) instances of Monad and confusion about (->)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310203/how-to-use-instances-of-monad-and-confusion-about)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as I said in the comments you basically have everything you need - the missing bit is just the technicality of wrapping/unwrapping the function from the `R` constructor.

ok here is how you make your `R` into a `Applicative` instance:

```
instance Applicative (R r) where
    pure a          = R (\_ -> a)
    (R f) <*> (R a) = R (\r -> (f r) (a r))
```

and yes this:

```
(<*>) :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

then translates into:

```
(<*>) :: R r (a -> b) -> R r a -> R r b
```

once you have this the call equivalent to your example just involves wrapping/unwrapping the function from the constructor:

```
run (R (+) <*> R (*2)) 5
```

---

in case you get some warning about a `Functor` instance: you need this too:

```
instance Functor (R r) where
    fmap f (R a) = R (\r -> f (a r))
```

Comment: Question1) I am puzzled by why `:t (Reader (+) <*> Reader (*2))` is `Num b => Reader b b`. Can you please explain or should I ask a new q? Question2) The first argument to `(<*>)` is `r (a -> b)` - why does it then typecheck to give `(+)`, which is `(r -> a -> b)`? Thanks.

Comment: it's because `(+)` is `Num c => c -> c -> c` - so if you look at the `r -> (a -> b)` (the essential of `R r (a -> b)`) and plug in `(+)` for it you need `r ~ c`, `a ~ c` and `b ~ c` - which yields the type (after renaming) ... btw: the first argument to `<*>` here is not `r (a -> b)` - it's `R r (a -> b)`