# Interpreting Haskell monad example

Tags: haskell, monads

I have this Haskell code that triples input value.

```
triple :: Int -> Int
triple = do
  n <- id
  d <- (n+)
  (d+)
```

How does this code work? With an example `triple 10`, how the argument `10` is mapped/assigned to `id`, `n` and `d` to get the return value of 30?

My understandig is as follows:

We can decompose `triple` function with two subfunctions `tripleA` and `tripleB` as follows:

```
triple :: Int -> Int
triple = tripleA >>= (\d -> tripleB d)

tripleA :: Int -> Int
tripleA = id >>= (\n -> (n+))

tripleB :: Int -> Int -> Int
tripleB d = (d+)
```

Now we can see that the function `tripleA` gets an input, assign it to `id` function to return the value itself, and map it to the function `(\n -> (n+))` to return `(10+) 10`.

Likewise, tripleB also makes `(20+) 20`, so I expect the results as 40, but the correct answer is 30.

What is wrong with my interpretation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use (->) instances of Monad and confusion about (->)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310203/how-to-use-instances-of-monad-and-confusion-about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite equivalent triple2 function as follows:

```
triple2 = (id >>= (\n -> (n+))) >>= (\d -> (d+))
```

With `f = \n -> (n+)`, we have `triple2 = (id >> f) >> f`.

From the definition of `>>=` in (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-645), we have

#### 1. id >>= f

```
\r -> f (id r) r = \r -> f r r = \r -> (r+) r
```

#### 2. (id >>= f) >>= f

```
x = id >>= f = \r -> (r+) r
x r = (r+) r
x >> f = \r -> f (x r) r = f ((r+) r) r = ((r+) r)+ r
```

so `((10+) 10)+ 10` makes `30`