# When to use or not to use 'return' in Haskell's monad expression

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a function a that 1) computes `(argument+) argument`, and 2) doubles it ([Interpreting Haskell monad example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626030/interpreting-haskell-monad-example)).

```
a :: Int -> Int 
a = (id >>= (\n -> (n+))) >>= (\d -> return (d + d))
```

In this function, I **should** use return to prevent errors.

However in this triple function that returns `((argument+) argument)+ argument)` to triple the input argument. I cannot use the return.

```
triplex :: Int -> Int 
triplex = (id >>= (\n -> (n+))) >>= (\d -> (d+))
```

From these examples, I guess simply the rule of `return` is 1) we use `return` when we return values, 2) we don't use `return` when we return a partial function. But I'm not sure this is correct understanding. So, Is there a rule behind this `return` in Haskell?

Comment: well yes - `return` is used to pull values up into your monad - as every other function you just have to look at the types (`return` is not what you know from C-like languages) - aside from this: why use the monad-instance of `(->) a` here at all? it just obfuscates everything - is this some exercise?

Comment: see: `\n -> (n+)` already has the desired type `Int -> (Int -> Int)` (your monad is `(->) Int`) - but of course `d+d` has not (it has type `Int`) - so you use `return (d+d) = \ _ -> (d+d)` (remember `the `\d -> ...` in `>>= (\d -> ...)` needs to return a monadic value - that is a `Int -> a` here )

Comment: @Carsten: Nice answer, I think you can answer the question for me accept the question unless better answers come along. BTW, I'm new to Haskell, so I'm trying to understand what monad in Haskell is.

Comment: This question does not deserve the down-vote, imho. Because it is an honest question by a beginner.

Comment: @prosseek, if I may, I think your approach to figuring out how to make it work is flawed: you are looking for "rules" which would give you an "algorithm" of sort, whereas I think the right approach is simply to understand the types of each part of the expression and how it works.

Comment: @prosseek You have asked a bunch of questions which are tailored to only one specific monad, the `(->) a` monad, which is not that much used. To get what's a monad is about I'd recommend you also play with other monads. Start from e.g. `Maybe` and `[]` and `Either e`, and then move to `State s`, `IO`, etc. Just focusing on one monad will not make you understand the whole picture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `return` function in Haskell has little to do with the `return` keyword in imperative programming languages—it’s just an ordinary function with an ordinary type signature:

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

Basically, `return` takes any old value and “lifts” it into a monad. It’s a little clearer what this function does when you replace the `m` with a concrete type, like `Maybe`:

```
return :: a -> Maybe a
```

There’s only one implementation of the above function, and that’s `Just`, so `return = Just` for the `Maybe` monad.

In your case, you are using the function monad, `(->) r`, also often called the “reader” monad. Performing the same substitution as with `Maybe`, we get the following signature:

```
return :: a -> r -> a
```

This function *also* has only one implementation, which is to ignore its second argument and return its first. This is what `const` does, so `return = const` for functions.

---

The question of “when to use `return`” is a reasonable one, but it should make more sense after understanding the above: you need to use `return` when the value returned from a function passed to `>>=` is not monadic, so it needs to be “lifted”. For example, the following would be a type error:

```
Just 3 >>= \x -> x + 1
```

Specifically, the right hand side needs to return a `Maybe Int`, but it only returns an `Int`. Therefore, we can use `return` to produce a value of the correct type:

```
Just 3 >>= \x -> return (x + 1)
```

However, consider a similar expression. In the following case, using `return` would be a type error:

```
Just [("a", 1), ("b", 2)] >>= \l -> lookup "c"
```

That’s because the result of the `lookup` function is *already* a `Maybe Int` value, so using `return` would produce a `Maybe (Maybe Int)`, which would be wrong.

Returning to your example using the function monad, `(n+)` is already a function of type `Int -> Int`, so using `return` would be incorrect (it would produce a function of type `Int -> Int -> Int`). However, `d + d` is just a value of type `Int`, so you need `return` to lift the value into the monad.

---

It’s worth noting that, in both cases, you could always replace `return` with its underlying implementation. You could use `Just` instead of `return` when using the `Maybe` monad, and you could use `const` instead of `return` when using the function monad. However, there are two good reasons to use `return`:

1. Using `return` lets you write functions that work with more than one kind of monad. That is, `return` gets you *polymorphism*.
2. It’s extremely idiomatic to use `return` to lift plain values into a monadic type, so it’s clearer and less noisy to always see `return` instead of seeing many different functions with different names.