# Applicative and Monad instances for a function type?

Tags: haskell, monads, instances

I have a data type that resembles `Blah` below but **because of a quirk with the type I cannot automatically derive Functor, Applicative, and Monad**.  So I must do it manually, but I'm not sure how.  I tried to take inspiration from the instances for `((->) a)`, but I can't quite figure out the Monad instance.

```
newtype Blah a = Blah (String -> a) -- deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

-- this seems right
instance Functor Blah where
  fmap f (Blah g) = Blah (f .  g)

instance Applicative Blah where
  pure = Blah . const
  -- This is right, right?
  (<*>) (Blah f) (Blah g) = Blah $ \x -> f x (g x)

instance Monad Blah where
  return = pure

  -- I'm not having any luck here.
  (>>=) a b = Blah $ \c -> _
```

Edit: Someone marked this as a duplicate of another, but I don't see where I would've gotten the answer from that.  The newtype wrapper is what made this difficult.  I looked up the `Monad` instance in base for `(->) a` before I wrote this question, but the gymnastics in the answer here are what I needed.

Comment: Why has this been marked down? It seems like a perfectly good question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use (->) instances of Monad and confusion about (->)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310203/how-to-use-instances-of-monad-and-confusion-about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
Blah f >>= g = Blah $ \s ->
    let Blah h = g $ f s in h s
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: This is the `Reader String` monad

Comment: I knew there would be a good example of exactly this out there somewhere, but I could not think of one.

Answer (score 2):

You can `derive` those instances. You just need to turn on the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` flag, which enables GHC to simply reuse the instance for the wrapped type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Blah a = Blah (String -> a) deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)
```

Comment: As I said in my original post, I cannot use deriving.  This is because I have class constraints on the type in my actual program.  It also isn't a newtype.

Comment: In that case, please give the _actual_ code you have.

Comment: The actual type is really large and overcomplicated and if I put it here it won't be answered for hours or maybe the rest of the day.  I just want this simple code to be answered in a reasonable time so I can spend the rest of the day (which is wide open at this point) working on my program rather than sitting around waiting.

Comment: @mindreader It's still a good idea to at least put in the bits that are preventing you from doing what you want to do. With the constraint issue, you might still be able to do automatic deriving using the `StandaloneDeriving` extension (if you had never mentioned the constraint thing, I never would have thought of that).

Comment: I get it, but I already tried standalone deriving, so I knew it wouldn't work.  I just didn't expect to get heavy down voting for merely rejecting a scenario an answer I explicitly said I wasn't interested in in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how you can derive this yourself using typed holes. Starting from your code, renamed a bit:

```
instance Monad Blah where
  return = pure
  f >>= g = Blah $ \s -> _
```

You’ll get a message like this:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: b
Relevant bindings include
  s :: String
  g :: a -> Blah b
  f :: Blah a
```

So we need to produce a `b`, given a `String`, a `Blah a`, and an `a -> Blah b`. Well, we already know how to produce an `a` from a `Blah a` and a `String`, by pattern-matching and applying the function in the `Blah`:

```
Blah f >>= g = Blah $ \s -> let h = f s in _
------                      -----------
```

Now we get:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: b
Relevant bindings include
  h :: a
  s :: String
  g :: a -> Blah b
  f :: String -> a
```

So we have an `a`, which we can give to `g` to get a `Blah b`, and pattern-matching on that gives us a `String -> b`:

```
Blah f >>= g = Blah $ \s -> let Blah h = g (f s) in _
                                ----------------
```

Now we get:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: b
Relevant bindings include
  h :: String -> b
  s :: String
  g :: a -> Blah b
  f :: String -> a
```

So we need a `b`, and we have a `String` and a `String -> b`. That’s easy:

```
Blah f >>= g = Blah $ \s -> let Blah h = g (f s) in h s
                                                    ---
```

And there you go, a correct implementation, guided by the types. You may also find it clearer if you define a helper function to “run” a `Blah`:

```
newtype Blah a = Blah { runBlah :: String -> a }
-- or:
runBlah :: Blah a -> String -> a
runBlah (Blah f) = f

instance Monad Blah where
  f >>= g = Blah $ \s -> runBlah (g (runBlah f s)) s
```