# Why does bind of the function instance supply the original value to the next computation?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming, bind, monads

As a functional Javascript developer with only a vague understanding of Haskell I really have a hard time to understand Haskell idioms like monads. When I look at `>>=` of the function instance

```
(>>=)  :: (r -> a) -> (a -> (r -> b)) -> r -> b

instance Monad ((->) r) where
f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r

// Javascript:
```

and its application with Javascript

```
const bind = f => g => x => g(f(x)) (x);

const inc = x => x + 1;

const f = bind(inc) (x => x <= 5 ? x => x * 2 : x => x * 3);


f(2); // 4
f(5); // 15
```

the monadic function `(a -> (r -> b))` (or `(a -> m b)`) provides a way to choose the next computation depending on the previous result. More generally, the monadic function along with its corresponding `bind` operator seems to give us the capability to define what function composition means in a specific computational context.

It is all the more surprising that the monadic function doesn't supply the result of the previous computation to the subsequent one. Instead, the original value is passed. I'd expect `f(2)`/`f(5)` to yield `6`/`18`, similar to normal function composition. Is this behavior specific to functions as monads? What do I misunderstand?

Comment: The rule of thumb is: `bind(...)(x => ...)` takes the value of the previous computation and binds it to `x`. Other lambdas `x => ...` (not after a bind) instead access the same implicit read-only argument, the one passed to `f` at the very beginning.

Comment: Side note: `x => x <= 5 ? x => x * 2 : x => x * 3` is unreadable, please use e.g. `x => x <= 5 ? y => y * 2 : z => z * 3` -- a computer does not care about alpha-equivalence, but humans do ;-)

Comment: Because it *must* - that function is the only valid implementation of a function whose type is `forall r a b . (r -> a) -> (a -> (r -> b)) -> r -> b` (except undefined, of course). The javascript function can of course do whatever it likes in the abscence of formal types, but then reasoning about it would be much harder (and called it `bind` would just be wrong)

Comment: That is precisely how `>>=` differs from `.` in the function monad. With `f . g`, `f` doesn't get any information about what was passed to `g`, only what `g` produced. With `g >>= f`, `f` gets *both* the input to *and* the output from of `g`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use (->) instances of Monad and confusion about (->)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310203/how-to-use-instances-of-monad-and-confusion-about)

Comment: Note that if your second function *wasn't* getting the output of `inc`, it would actually return 10. You only get 15 because `inc` turns the 5 into a 6 before the second function does the `x <= 5` test, which triggers multiplication of the *other* parameter by 3 instead of 2. Your `f(5)` case is actually precisely what you needed to demonstrate that the behaviour is more complicated than *either* "both functions get the same input" or "the second gets the output of the first".

Comment: @Cactus Your link is indeed helpful, still I don't think my question is a dupe, because it is more specific and more importantly, it is a cross language. I know that the monad concept is language agnostic, but people are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your confusion arises from using functions that are too simple. In particular, you write

```
const inc = x => x + 1;
```

whose type is a function that returns values in the *same* space as its input. Let's say `inc` is dealing with integers. Because both its input and output are integers, if you have another function `foo` that takes integers, it is easy to imagine using the *output* of `inc` as an *input* to `foo`.

The real world includes more exciting functions, though. Consider the function `tree_of_depth` that takes an integer and creates a tree of strings of that depth. (I won't try to implement it, because I don't know enough javascript to do a convincing job of it.) Now all of a sudden it's harder to imagine passing the output of `tree_of_depth` as an input to `foo`, since `foo` is expecting integers and `tree_of_depth` is producing trees, right? The only thing we can pass on to `foo` is the *input* to `tree_of_depth`, because that's the only integer we have lying around, even after running `tree_of_depth`.

Let's see how that manifests in the Haskell type signature for bind:

```
(>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> (r -> b)
```

This says that `(>>=)` takes two arguments, each functions. The first function can be of any old type you like -- it can take a value of type `r` and produce a value of type `a`. In particular, you don't have to promise that `r` and `a` are the same at all. But once you pick its type, then the type of the next function argument to `(>>=)` is constrained: it has to be a function of two arguments whose types are the *same* `r` and `a` as before.

Now you can see why we have to pass the same value of type `r` to both of these functions: the first function produces an `a`, not an updated `r`, so we have no other value of type `r` to pass to the second function! Unlike your situation with `inc`, where the first function happened to also *produce* an `r`, we may be producing some other very different type.

This explains why bind has to be implemented the way it is, but maybe doesn't explain why this monad is a useful one. There is writing elsewhere on that. But the canonical use case is for configuration variables. Suppose at program start you parse a configuration file; then for the rest of the program, you want to be able to influence the behavior of various functions by looking at information from that configuration. In all cases it makes sense to use the same configuration information -- it doesn't need to change. Then this monad becomes useful: you can have an implicit configuration value, and the monad's bind operation makes sure that the two functions you're sequencing both have access to that information without having to manually pass it in to both functions.

P.S. You say

> It is all the more surprising that the monadic function doesn't supply the result of the previous computation to the subsequent one.

which I find slightly imprecise: in fact in `m >>= f`, the function `f` gets *both* the result of `m` (as its first argument) *and* the original value (as its second argument).

Comment: Great, extensive response, Thanks! `r` and `a` can be of different type of course. And with the given type for `>>=`, no other valid implementation is possible. What I like about `(->)` instances of Monads, Applicatives and Functors is that that they are a familiar concept (combinators) applied within another concept, which is quite strange to me. They are a suitable starting point to understand this new concept. Programming to mathematical interfaces is hard, especially in Javascript where you can just make stuff up. I guess I just took another step forward. Thanks again!

Comment: Functions can be seen as a kind of type constructor, because they may transform an `r` in an `a` of different type. When `m a`/`m b` within `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` are functions of type `(r -> a)`/`(r -> b)`, there is no alternative for `(r -> b)` to ignore the result `a` of the previous operation. Provided that `(r -> a)` is of type `(r -> r)` you can use the `K` combinator to pass the computed value to `(r -> b)`, because `K` is `return` for the function instance. Sorry if I should repeat myself, but I finally understood it.

Answer (score 1):

> More generally, the monadic function along with its corresponding bind
>   operator seems to give us the capability to define what function
>   composition means in a specific computational context.

I'm not sure what you mean by the "monadic function". Monads (which in Haskell consist of a bind function and a pure function) let you express **how a series of monadic actions can be chained together** ([`(<=<)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-60--61--60-) is the monad equivalent of composition, equivalent to `(.)` for the [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) monad). In that sense, you do sort of get composition, but only composition of *actions* (functions of the form `a -> m b`).

(This is further abstracted in the [`Kleisli`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:Kleisli) newtype around functions of the type `a -> m b`. Its [category instance](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Control.Arrow.html#line-151) really lets you write the sequencing of monadic actions as composition.)

> I'd expect f(2)/f(5) to yield 6/18, similar to normal function composition.

Then, you can just use normal function composition! Don't use a monad if you don't need one.

> It is all the more surprising that the monadic function doesn't supply
>   the result of the previous computation to the subsequent one. Instead,
>   the original value is passed.   ...   Is this behavior specific to
>   functions as monads?

Yes, it it. The monad `Monad ((->) r)` is also known as the "reader monad" because it only *reads* from its environment. That said, as far as monads are concerned, you *are* still passing the monadic result of the previous action to the subsequent one - but those results are themselves functions!

Comment: OK, I won't use monadic function anymore, but _action_ or _kleisli arrow_. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by chi, this line

```
const f = bind(inc) (x => x <= 5 ? x => x * 2 : x => x * 3);
```

would be clearer as something like

```
const f = bind(inc) (x => x <= 5 ? y => y * 2 : y => y * 3);
```

the `Monad` instance for functions is basically the `Reader` monad. You have a value `x => x + 1` that depends on an enviroment (it adds 1 to the environment).

You also have a function which, depending on its input, returns one value that depends on an environment (`y => y * 2`) or another value that depends on an environment (`y => y * 3`).

In your `bind`, you are only using the result of `x => x + 1` to *choose* between these two functions. Your are not returning the previous result *directly*. But you could, if you returned *constant functions* which *ignored* their environments and returned a fixed value depending only on the previous result:

```
const f = bind(inc) (x => x <= 5 ? _ => x * 2 : _ => x * 3);
```

(not sure about the syntax)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess your last example is rather an unusual use of `bind`, right?

Comment: Not at all! Every `Monad` instance definition requires, besides `bind`, another function that puts a pure value in a "neutral" context. In Haskell that other function is (confusingly) named `return`. `return` for the function/Reader monads in just the constant function that receives the environment and ignores it.

Comment: ah, `return` of the `(->)` instance is just the `K` combinator. Got it!